# Wanting to draw a slope graph with the two datasets I have

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I am currently analysing street crime data from April 2016 - March 2017.  I have discovered the same crime data from April 2015 to March 2016.  I am wanting to compare the two datasets I have in the form of a 'slope graph', to show the changes in crime occurrences by crime type over these two datasets.

This is my code to create a pie chart for Apr 15 to Mar 16.

```
b = apr15tomar16.groupby('Crime type').size()
print (b)
plt.title('Crimes by Crime type from April 2015 to March 2016')
b.plot.pie(figsize=(10,10), autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

[Pie chart showing crimes from April 2015 to March 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcTO.png)

This is my code to create a pie chart for Apr 16 to Mar 17.

```
c = apr16tomar17.groupby('Crime type').size()
print (c)
plt.title('Crimes by Crime type from April 2016 to March 2017')
c.plot.pie(figsize=(10,10), autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

[Pie chart showing crimes from April 2016 to March 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEl6x.png)

I feel like I am on the right track, however I am not too sure how to be able to compare these.  Ideally I'd like to use a slope graph.  Any direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I envision a graph like this:
[Slope graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIIIu.jpg)

Comment: What is a "slope graph"? Would you be able to draw what you envision with pen and paper? Otherwise I think this question is not useful as there are just too many options to visualize some dataset and this shouldn't end up with random guessing.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited my question and at the bottom there is an example of what I envision.  Apologies for being too vague.

Comment: That would just be a line plot with two points for each data set. What is the problem of producing such plot? Mind that you cannot expect any help if you don't provide a [mcve] and a clear problem description (not just a task dump).